# Youtube Data API v3 oAuth2 failing to change permissions

Tags: youtube, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, authorization, google-oauth

I am using google's apis to create a small desktop application to make uploading videos easier to manage (I manage a network hub channel, long story as to why I need this). I've followed google's guides to get a starting point, but the authentication using oauth2 fails with the following console output:

```
    Sep 12, 2015 9:43:29 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody: C:\Users\BossLetsPlays\.oauth-credentials
Sep 12, 2015 9:43:29 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for owner: C:\Users\BossLetsPlays\.oauth-credentials
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
java.io.IOException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver.getRedirectUri(LocalServerReceiver.java:107)
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:76)
    at com.bossletsplays.ytclient.utils.AuthUtil.authorize(AuthUtil.java:67)
    at com.bossletsplays.ytclient.utils.VideoUploader.upload(VideoUploader.java:48)
    at com.bossletsplays.ytclient.gui.MainGui$4.actionPerformed(MainGui.java:152)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.newServerSocket(SocketConnector.java:80)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.open(SocketConnector.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:283)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.doStart(SocketConnector.java:147)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:235)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver.getRedirectUri(LocalServerReceiver.java:104)
    ... 40 more
```

I've seen the issue many places online but no working solutions. Google says the bug is fixed by throwing warnings instead of IOExceptions, but I get both warnings and IOExceptions still.

Here is the code that handles the authentication:

```
public static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT        = new NetHttpTransport();
public static final JsonFactory   JSON_FACTORY          = new JacksonFactory();
private static final String       CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY = ".oauth-credentials";

public static Credential authorize(List<String> scopes, String credentialDatastore) throws IOException {
    Reader clientSecretReader = new InputStreamReader(AuthUtil.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json"));
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, clientSecretReader);
    System.out.println(clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId());
    if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
            || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
        System.out.println(
                "Enter Client ID and Secret from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=youtube"
                        + "into src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    FileDataStoreFactory fileDataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(
            new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/" + CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY));
    DataStore<StoredCredential> datastore = fileDataStoreFactory.getDataStore(credentialDatastore);
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, scopes).setCredentialDataStore(datastore)
                    .build();
    LocalServerReceiver localReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8080).build();

    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, localReceiver).authorize("user");
}
```

And yes I have replaced the client id and secrets in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs in the line :

```
LocalServerReceiver localReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8080).build();
```

May be the port 8080 is used by another process ...

To be sure run the command :

```
netstat -an | grep 8080
```

after that search for the process and kill it

Comment: Thanks! Turns out that port was being used by apache xamp... Switched the port of the local receiver to 1043 and it all works fine now